# Quick help on why this extension is of degree $2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

The set up is,

> Splitting field $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\alpha)$ where $\alpha=2^{\frac{1}{4}} \in \mathbb{R}$. The three obvious subfields of $K$ with degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are..?

Answer is apprently,

> $\mathbb{Q}(i),\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{2})$.

I have a problem as to understanding why some of these are degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now, $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has elements of the form $p+qi$. So sure, over $\mathbb{Q}$ it has basis $\{1,i\}$ so it is degree $2$ for $\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}$.

However, $\mathbb{Q}(i \sqrt{2})$ has elements of the form $p+qi\alpha+r\alpha^2+si\alpha^3$ yes?(Am I missing anything..?). So, over, $\mathbb{Q}$, the basis is $\{1,i\alpha,\alpha^2,i\alpha^3\}$...it seems to me. I cannot reduce the number of elements in the basis here can I?
Then this tells me the degree is $4$ instead of $2$.

Can someone correct me of my mistakes here?

Comment: What is $(i\sqrt 2)^2$?  Is it in $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: (Note that $i+\sqrt2$ is a different story...)

Comment: that's $-2$ i guess. And yes it is in the rationals....but does that have something to do with my mistake?$\alpha^2=\sqrt{2}$ so I'll need that in my basis over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Q(i\sqrt2\,)$ is the smallest field containing $i\sqrt2$. You can’t get $\sqrt2$ by applying addition, subtraction, multiplication, division to expressions involving $i\sqrt2$ only.

Comment: oh, right, so $\sqrt{2}$ isn't supposed to be in my basis?

Comment: Right. Nor $i$. Just two things in the basis.